# mysql - SELECT data from date range

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I want to select users on my database who are registered before 1 month ago. How I do it? please explain it. Thanks 
Here my DB structure

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need convert timestamp to datetime first.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(activation_time) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: to let it convert from time to datetime

Comment: how about DATEDIFF function? Can i use it?

Comment: it use to check 2 days different. so cannot

Comment: What is the problem with just activation_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH

Comment: because he want to get 1 month ago data. so i need to get today day then minus 1 month :)

Comment: Should i remove default value of timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE activation_time BETWEEN 20-10-2014 AND 20-9-2014;
```